# Selecionar vetores de ID com determinadas características no R

Tags: array, r, dplyr

Possuo um data frame com quatro colunas de valores para cada ID e preciso criar um novo df excluindo os ID cujos vetores tenham mais de um zero ou mais de um NA.

Eu criei o DF

```
library(dplyr)
co_entidade<-c(23, 40, 58, 82, 104, 171,    198, 201, 202,244)
depend<-c(2,3,4,4,4,4,4,2,3,4)
mat13<-c(42,    218,    1397,   0,    393,    283, 1053,  529,    NA, 664)
mat14<-c(44,    222,    1300,   0,    428,    246,    994,    521,    NA, 678)
mat15<-c(40,    215,    1345,   199,    0,    226,    1069,   566,    NA, 598)
mat16<-c(10,    208,    1442,   154,    0,    229,    1033,    NA,    521,552)

df<-data.frame(co_entidade, depend, mat13, mat14, mat15, mat16)
df
```

[image: Matriculas 2013 a 2016 por entidade]

Eu tentei aplicar um filtro com o pacote dplyr que até retira os 0 e NAs, mas o sistema retorna os ids separados por ano, conforme imagem abaixo

```
desc_0_NA <- df %>% 
            gather(mat_tipo, mat_valor, mat13:mat16) %>%
            filter(mat_valor>0, mat_valor!="NA")
desc_0_NA
```

[image: Resultado do comando]

Mas, o que preciso é retirar os co_entidade que apresente mais de um valor 0 ou NA, neste meu exemplo eu terei que obter um df sem os códigos 82, 104 e 202, sublinhados em vermelho na imagem abaixo. Já que esses vetores (82 e 104) apresentam mais de um zero ou mais de um NA (202).

[image: IDs a serem filtrados]

Se alguém souber como fazer isso no R, independentemente dos anos onde estejam os zeros ou NAs.

Desde já agradeço

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro eu criei uma função `is.0()` nos moldes da `is.na()` para testar se o valor da célula é igual a 0

```
is.0 <- function(x){x == 0}
```

Depois utilizei as funções do pacote `dplyr`

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(S.0 = rowSums(is.0(.), na.rm = T),
         S.NA = rowSums(is.na(.))) %>% 
  filter(S.0 <= 1) %>% 
  filter(S.NA <= 1) %>% 
  select(-contains("S."))
df
```